# How can I get the size of the inner part of a frame?

Tags: java

How can I get the size of the inner part of a frame? I mean the part that components can be added on.

When I'm using `.NET` languages like `VB` and `C#`, I do some trick. I add a panel or something alike to my form and make it fill the form (using dock property in Windows Forms), and then use its size.

I have tried hard to do this in `Java`, but no success. I tried to add a `JPanel` to CENTER of my `JFrame` using a `BorderLayout`, but although the panel fills the frame, all the size-relative functions of the `JPanel` return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way seems to work. But:

- You don't need to manually add a `JPanel`. `getContentPane()` is suitable.
- If you want to get its size. You need to

  1. Makes this JFrame displayable by connecting it to a native screen resource.
  2. Revalidates the JFrame.

`setVisible(true)` do these for you. But if you do not want to make the `JFrame` visible, you can use `addNotify` and `revalidate`.

Example:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                Container c = f.getContentPane();
                f.setSize(800, 600);
                System.out.println(c.getSize()); // width=0,height=0
                f.addNotify();
                f.revalidate();
                System.out.println(c.getSize()); // width=784,height=562
                f.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println(c.getSize()); // width=784,height=562
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [getContentPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane%28%29) and [getWidth](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getWidth%28%29)/[getHeight](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getHeight%28%29):

```
getContentPane().getWidth()

getContentPane().getHeight()
```

Tested with a simple 1440x900 frame and I get 1424x862

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling size related functions when the frame is not yet visible.
You can use:

```
getContentPane().getSize();
```

after invoking frame's setVisible(true) method. Getting the size of the panel added to the center of the frame, as you did before, will also work, after setting the frame to be visible.